# I'm setting the category as the url in django and i'm getting error that ';' expected.javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, jinja2

I'm setting the category as the url in django and i'm getting error that  ';' expected.javascript

```
{% for category in all_categories %}
    <div onclick="location.href='{% url 'category' category.category %}';"
        style="box-shadow:0 5px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);"
        class="hover:scale-105 hover:transform transition duration-300 cursor-pointer bg-gray-900 rounded-lg h-40 w-full my-4 text-center p-5 grid place-items-center">
        <div>
            <p class='text-4xl my-2'><i
                    class="bi bi-tags text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-200 to-blue-500"></i>
            </p>
            <p class='text-base'>{{ category.category }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]. Please consider taking a [tour] of the site. To learn how to ask questions, see [ask]. Also see the importance of a [example].

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick='location.href="{% url 'category' category.category %}";'
```

are you sure that the inner field in category model is called category !?

if it doesn't work, I recommend to construct the URL in JS

Comment: you could try this if the previous option not worked for you : onclick='location.href="category/{{category.category}}";'

Comment: Thank you Israa, unfortunately above is not workin

Comment: onclick='location.href="{% url 'app_name:category' category.category %}";'  could ypu try this ?